# Azure Data Factory Data Flow Flatten Transformation with Rule based Mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was working on an xml file to flatten and load into a stage area. The xml hierarchy array elements have different number of columns. For Eg:
author element contains: id,name,book in one file and in the next files could contain an additional column with the name publishername.

I have tried using rule based mapping expression to fix this issue with the following expression like (name,'publishername%').

But its not returning the column and records if exists? Is there any solution for this? Any help would be aprreciated.

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: have you tried the XSD Validation mode and Name space checked in source option in XML settings?

Answer (score 0):

- In Flatten transformation, Click `+Add mapping` and then click `Rule based mapping`

[image]

- In my sample XML file, under catalog.book, I had sub-column named `Author`. Here, I tested if sub-columns named `Author` and `PublishersName` exist. If exist, those columns are mapped to output. To do this,
- In source column, Type `locate('author',lower(name))==1` and give the hierarchy level at which the sub-column exists.  And Name it as `Author`.
  The expression `locate('author',lower(name))==1` returns `true` if the substring `'author'` is found at the beginning of the column name, and `false` otherwise.
- Similarly, for sub-column `PublishersName` also, similar expression is given.

[image]

- Output has only author column. Since there is no column with the name `PublishersName%` in the input, there is no such column in the sink.

[image]